# awk command to get all records from log file based on timestamp range in python

Tags: python, linux, logging, awk

I need to get all the records between two timestamp 1 to timestamp 2.
The here is an example of two timestamps : 2016-03-21T11:20:27 , 2016-03-21T11:40:27

here is what I have tried:

```
import subprocess

query = '$0 ~ /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/ \
{ \
    if ($1T$2 >= "2016-03-21T11:20:27") p=1; \
    if ($1T$2 >= "2016-03-21T11:40:27") p=2; \
} \
p {print $0}' 


output = subprocess.Popen(['awk', query,'nat.csv.2016032112.csv.gz'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

I am not sure what I am missing.

---

Edit: Input from zgrep command and output

command: 
    zgrep "192.168.224.63,39713" nat.csv.2016032112.csv.gz

output: (2 records are return)

2016-03-21T11:01:13.054-04:00,2,172.21.63.13,49766,17.167.195.12,443,192.168.224.63,39713,6,16,1438,13,6506
2016-03-21T11:31:16.528-04:00,54,172.21.63.24,59014,77.68.41.125,51900,192.168.224.63,39713,6,182,236501,125,6437

with this i can parse the fields to return the ip address and port numbers for other use. Since I want the data between a range, between timestamp A and timestamp B, I would like to filter anything outside of that range.

---

Edit 2
Arguments provided

```
ip address: 192.168.224.154

port: 36715

log: nat.csv.2016032100.csv.gz

start: 2016-03-20T23:12:00

end: 2016-03-20T23:22:00
```

Input

```
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00,60,172.21.154.211,40500,24.43.1.206,18313,192.168.224.154,36715,17,2,454,1,129
2016-03-20T23:12:22.714-04:00,16,172.21.154.161,61130,31.13.73.7,80,192.168.224.154,36715,6,4,172,2,92
```

Results provided by:

```
zgrep "192.168.224.154,36715" nat.csv.2016032100.csv.gz
```

Output

```
2016-03-20T23:12:22.714-04:00,16,172.21.154.161,61130,31.13.73.7,80,192.168.224.154,36715,6,4,172,2,92
```

The first record should not be return. Its a bit hard to get good examples, most return 2 records.

---

here is what a chuck of the log

```
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   19  172.21.128.70   61807   154.70.22.157   15702   192.168.224.128 61065   6   3   152 0   0
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   19  172.19.172.152  57681   189.110.82.196  1024    192.168.226.172 41197   6   3   152 0   0
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   19  172.19.165.121  24598   222.89.181.20   9094    192.168.226.165 32628   6   5   300 0   0
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   19  172.25.47.36    58797   192.168.0.6 49201   192.168.244.2   36050   6   7   448 0   0
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   19  172.19.165.121  24254   114.228.60.157  58782   192.168.226.165 51470   6   1   60  0   0
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   4   172.19.168.238  57419   8.8.4.4 53  192.168.226.168 51143   17  1   60  1   76
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   4   172.21.134.249  58220   8.8.4.4 53  192.168.224.134 50374   17  1   68  1   267
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   3   172.19.131.110  52480   156.154.70.22   53  192.168.226.131 53024   17  1   68  1   166
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   3   172.19.131.110  64935   156.154.70.22   53  192.168.226.131 53193   17  1   67  1   155
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   68  172.19.212.211  52537   31.13.73.1  443 192.168.226.212 62342   6   24  4426    20  5142
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   77  172.19.170.63   51375   104.73.87.51    443 192.168.226.170 54179   6   9   860 7   553
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   43  172.19.170.63   60547   23.15.135.11    80  192.168.226.170 42232   6   5   212 4   585
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   44  172.19.170.63   60530   23.15.135.18    80  192.168.226.170 47914   6   5   212 4   585
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   73  172.19.153.239  54157   199.16.156.6    443 192.168.226.153 42815   6   16  4429    12  6298
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   76  172.19.170.63   51393   104.73.87.51    443 192.168.226.170 58126   6   9   1407    7   862
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   6   172.21.155.59   57297   54.225.73.60    80  192.168.224.155 45142   6   7   980 6   897
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   7   172.21.155.59   57283   8.43.72.32  80  192.168.224.155 55636   6   9   4855    7   868
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   7   172.21.155.59   57275   23.235.39.175   80  192.168.224.155 58325   6   33  3674    44  59257
2016-03-20T23:00:01.671-04:00   6   172.21.155.59   57304   23.21.59.91 80  192.168.224.155 49043   6   7   2921    6   2384
```

i used the zgrep command to parse for records i need. Also, to limit the results.

Comment: How does what your code actually does differ from what you wanted it to do?

Comment: I used to have a query that took a timestamp and return the exact record within the logs. i used grep then. 

    query = ["zgrep", " '", ip_address, ",", port_number, "' ", log_file]
    query = "".join(query)

    records.append([subprocess.Popen(query, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()])

But, now we want to see what is happening between two log timestamps within the logs. I don't believe that grep is the best way to handle ranges. I seen online people using either sed or awk commands. I never used either one of them before. 

right now nothing is displayed.

Comment: second if statement should set `p=0` for this to work as intended.  Better exit at that point if your log is already ordered.

Answer (score 1):

you can rewrite awk script as follows

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{key=$1"T"$2}
         key >= "2016-03-21T11:20:27" {p=1}
         key >= "2016-03-21T11:40:27" {exit}
         p'
```

you can delegate the time stamp regex match to zgrep as well.

Comment: Hi karakfa, i used your code snip it within the python application and it works. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

One definite problem you have is that `$1T$2` is concatenating $1 with the contents of an uninitialized (and so a numeric-string with value 0-or-NULL) variable named T and then $2 so it's the same as just doing `$1$2`. You probably meant `$1"T"$2`:

```
query = '/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/ \
{ \
    if ($1"T"$2 >= "2016-03-21T11:20:27") p=1; \
    if ($1"T"$2 >= "2016-03-21T11:40:27") p=2; \
} \
p'
```

I tweaked a little to make it more awk-ish too.

Less likely to be an issue is that some awks might not understand `{2}` (e.g. pre-4.0 GNU awks without `--re-interval`).

Having said that: Excuse the ignorance but  why do you have to call awk to do this? Doesn't python have some way of reading files and comparing text?

Also if `nat.csv.2016032112.csv.gz` is the name of the file you're trying to use as input to awk then you will have a problem if that file really is gzipped (guessing from `.gz` suffix) since awk only runs on text files.

Given your update question I THINK this might be what you want from an awk script:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    beg = "2016-03-20T23:12:00"
    end = "2016-03-20T23:22:00"
}
match($0,/^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}T[0-2][0-9](:[0-5][0-9]){2}/) {
    cur = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
cur >= beg { inBlock = 1 }
inBlock
cur >= end { inBlock = 0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
2016-03-20T23:12:22.714-04:00,16,172.21.154.161,61130,31.13.73.7,80,192.168.224.154,36715,6,4,172,2,92
```

It's not clear when you say "between" if you mean include or exclude lines matching the start and/or end values. Whatever you need you just reorder or tweak the math in the last 3 lines above to accomplish.

Given what I now know about your input format all you actually need is:

```
awk '$0>="2016-03-20T23:12:00"{p=1} p; $0>="2016-03-20T23:22:00"{p=0}'
```

Comment: Each log is about 4Gb, I was planning on doing something similar to this: zgrep ipaddress.portnumber logfile | awk timerange_filter. The awk would filter the results given back by zgrep. At least this was the plan.

Comment: Would you happen to know a better way in parsing the data given you know the start time, end time and file to search? Once a record(s) is returned, the record fields can be parsed. The data pulled back will be used to query a database(s). Python has modules like subprocess that allows terminal interactions within python.

Comment: I edited my post above to show an example from the .csv.gz file.

I just to work on how to get the terminal to display correctly. I then know how to port it over to python.

Comment: Thank Ed, that works. I'm using this to test my python application against. I went with the answer that karakfa given within my python program. I will continue working on my communication, I been told at work that Ihave issues explaining myself, thank you for your feedback :)

Comment: You're welcome and that's fine but you should be aware that @karakfa's script makes no sense given your input file. Given an input line like `2016-03-20T23:12:22.714-04:00,16,172.21.154.161,...`, for example, `$1` contains `2016-03-20T23:12:22.714-04:00` while $2 contains `16` so that script is creating a key that is `2016-03-20T23:12:22.714-04:00T16` for comparison with a timestamp like `2016-03-20T23:12:00`. Sure, it'll produce the output you expect but it just doesn't make any sense to do it that way. I added a script to my answer that does what you need with minimal code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ed Morton and karakfa for your feedback.

Here is the command running in terminal:

Command in terminal

```
zgrep "192.168.224.63,39713" nat.csv.2016032112.csv.gz | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{key=$1"T"$2} key >= "2016-03-21T11:20:27" {p=1} key >= "2016-03-21T11:40:27" {exit} p'
```

Results (unfiltered, without awk)

```
2016-03-21T11:01:13.054-04:00,2,172.21.63.13,49766,17.167.195.12,443,192.168.224.63,39713,6,16,1438,13,6506
2016-03-21T11:31:16.528-04:00,54,172.21.63.24,59014,77.68.41.125,51900,192.168.224.63,39713,6,182,236501,125,6437
```

Results (filtered, with awk)

```
2016-03-21T11:31:16.528-04:00,54,172.21.63.24,59014,77.68.41.125,51900,192.168.224.63,39713,6,182,236501,125,6437
```

### So, here is the python code:

```
import subprocess

ip_address = '192.168.224.63'
port_number = '39713'
log_file = 'nat.csv.2016032112.csv.gz'
start_time = '2016-03-21T11:20:27'
stop_time = '2016-03-21T11:40:27'

terminal_commands = {}
terminal_commands['zgrep'] = ["zgrep", " '", ip_address, ",", port_number, "' ", log_file]
terminal_commands['awk'] = ["awk -F, -v OFS=, '{key=$1\"T\"$2} key >= \"",start_time,"\" {p=1} key >= \"",stop_time,"\" {exit} p'"]

query_commands = {}
query_commands['zgrep'] = ''.join(str(x) for x in terminal_commands['zgrep'])
query_commands['awk'] = ''.join(str(x) for x in terminal_commands['awk'])
query_commands['run_query'] = '|'.join((query_commands['zgrep'], query_commands['awk']))

records = []
records.append([subprocess.Popen(query_commands['run_query'], shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()])
print records
```